# Option to have Experience and Education sections expanded in public view

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Colleagues whom I have asked to review my resume reported that they did not immediately understand that they could click on the arrow next to the Experience and Education entries to see the full details of the position.  They saw the grey arrow and interpreted it as just a bullet, not an expander.

It might be easier for a new user to understand and review a resume if these sections were initially  (optionally?) expanded instead of collapsed.

Comment: I second this concern.  I'm not comfortable using my Careers page as my resume when the most important sections default to being hidden.